# Could not cast value of type '_SwiftValue' (0x1106695f8) to 'NSArray' (0x110112598)

Tags: swift, dictionary, swifty-json

I am fetching JSON dictionary data and appending them into a [[String:Anyobject]] variable but when i try to put fetched "image" data . as [String] array in a variable it prints nil when i try to print the array elements as [String]

var productsDetails = [String: AnyObject]

```
            guard let response = data else {return}

            if response["success"].boolValue == true , error == nil{

                //cell.titleLabel.text = response["data"]["product"]["title"] as? String
                self.productsDetails.append(response["data"]["product"].dictionary! as [String : AnyObject])

            }
            self.cartTableView.reloadData()
```

in table view cell

```
    let data = self.productsDetails[indexPath.row]
    cell.titleLabel.text =  "\(data["title"]!)"

    cell.amountLabel.text = "\(data["price"]!)"

    cell.decriptionLabel.text = "\(data["details"]!)"

    let strum :[String] = (data["image"]! as? [String])! // this line is giving error
    print(strum) 

    print(String(describing: type(of: data["image"])))
    return cell
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all a JSON dictionary in Swift 3+ is never `[String:AnyObject]`, it's `[String:Any]`

The error is clear. `data["image"]` contains a (Swifty)JSON object, that's the mentioned `_SwiftValue` type.

To get a dictionary of `product` use `dictionaryObject` which returns `[String:Any]?`

```
self.productsDetails.append(response["data"]["product"].dictionaryObject!)
```

And please don't use a horrible syntax like `(data["image"]! as? [String])!` which is

> *force downcast an optional to an optional and then force unwrap it*.

If it's supposed to be optional downcast it conditionally (`data["image"] as? [String]`) or force downcast it once  (`data["image"] as! [String]`)

Note: You are encouraged to drop SwiftyJSON in favor of `Codable`. It's built-in and more efficient.

Comment: thank you so much @vadian .. problem is solved by using dictionaryObject .. and your solution is clean and i will take care of my syntax choice . as am novice. thank you very much